# If $V=U_1+U_2+U_3$ and $U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3 = 0$($0$ as vectorial subspace), then V = $U_1\oplus U_2 \oplus U_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a vectorial space over a field $K$ and $U_1, U_2, U_3$ vectorial subspaces of V. If $V=U_1+U_2+U_3$ and $U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3 = 0$ 
($0$ as vectorial subspace), then V = $U_1\oplus U_2 \oplus U_3$ ? 
What I've tried:
I gave a counterexample:
Let $U_1 = \Bigl\langle \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\Bigl\rangle,U_2=\Bigl\langle\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\Bigl\rangle$, $U_3=\Bigl\langle\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\Bigl\rangle$. So, $U_1 \cap U_2 \cap U_3 = 0$, $V=U_1+U_2+U_3$, but $U_1 \cap (U_2+U_3) \supset \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, so $U_1\oplus U_2 \oplus U_3 \neq V$. Am I wrong ?

Comment: look at $U_1=K(0,1),U_2=K(1,1),U_3=K(1,0)$.

Comment: The final containment that you wrote is incorrect, since $U_2+U_3=U_3$ intersects $U_1$ trivially. For a counterexample I would avoid having one of the $U_i$'s be the zero subspace. Kenta's example is a good counterexample.

Comment: Your counter example is wrong. But you are right to try to find a counterexemple, because the statement is wrong as well.

Comment: @Surb sorry, I've written (0,0,0) instean of (0,1,0). It's good now?

Comment: It seems true now, after your edit.